# i don't seem to understand the error here

Tags: python, syntax

```
pac = PassiveAggressiveClassifier(max_iter= 50)
pac.fit(tfidf_train,y_train)

y_pred=pac.predict(tfidf_test)
score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

print (f 'Accuracy: {round(score*100,2)} %')
```

then run I get this output

`File "<ipython-input-16-e007e46bb28d>", line 7 print (f 'Accuracy: {round(score*100,2)} %') ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You have a typo. There is no need to have a space after `f` in f-strings.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space between `f` and the single quote. Remove it.

```
print (f'Accuracy: {round(score*100,2)} %')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
`print (f 'Accuracy: {round(score*100,2)} %')`

into this:
`print(f'Accuracy: {round(score*100,2)} %')`

When you copy the code from somewhere else, check the syntax.